# Configure ssh-key path to use for a specific host

Tags: ssh-keys, known-hosts

When connecting via SSH my terminal wants to use id_rsa by default. I don't want to use that key for this particular server. So I am forced to specify the proper key path when connecting:

This works to connect:
**ssh -i /Users/myuser/.ssh/mykey  serveruser@server.com**

But I would prefer to use the following to connect:
**ssh user@server.com**

**My Question**:
Is there a way to indicate in known_hosts or other config that SSH should use the key located at ***/Users/myuser/.ssh/mykey*** when ***serveruser*** is connecting to ***server.com***?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using a function or script to replace `ssh`? It is then a straightforward task to scan the parameters and add the extra parameter to use the other key when connecting to `server.com`.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

One option you could consider would be to user the .ssh/config file.

Example: .ssh/config

```
Host server.com
    HostName server.com
    User serveruser
    IdentityFile /Users/myuser/.ssh/mykey
```

By doing this you could execute "ssh server.com".  The config file would use the specified Username and Identity File.

Comment: Addition: You can use `~/.ssh/mykey` for a local key file, also on Windows.

Comment: Note that if you don't have the config file in your .ssh folder you must create it first and note that the User line is optional

Comment: Furthermore the `HostName` line is not required in this example, as it just tells the ssh client how to resolve the `Host` value (e.g. if you want to use a short alias there).

Answer (score 3):

An additional option would be to use ssh-agent.

If you add all of your identities to it

```
ssh-add .ssh/id_rsa
ssh-add .ssh/mykey
```

When you connect to the remote host, the one that works is the one that is used.

Comment: Doesn't work. I have too many entities. It just fails to login due to too many tries